# Goose NoClassDefFound Error

Tags: javascript, android, goose

I am trying to implement Goose-2.1.22 into one of my applications. However, when I try to run my app with the basic code they provided me I get this error:

```
02-16 11:19:55.048  29391-29391/test.package.test2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gravity.goose.Goose
        at test.package.test2.Searching_Animation_Screen.goose_it(Searching_Animation_Screen.java:65)
        at test.package.test2.Searching_Animation_Screen.onCreate(Searching_Animation_Screen.java:59)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)\
```

Here is the code that uses goose (method called from `onCreate()`)

```
String url = "http://www.cnn.com/2010/POLITICS/08/13/democrats.social.security/index.html";
    Goose goose = new Goose(new Configuration());
    Article article = goose.extractContent(url);
    System.out.println(article.cleanedArticleText());
    text.setText(article.cleanedArticleText().toString());
```

Any ideas how to fix my issue? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It seems library (jar) is not in your APK.

If you use Eclipse, right click on your project, select "Java build Path", check Goose jar is in tab "Libraries" and in tab "Order & export", Goose lib must be present and checked.

Comment: No, it is. I placed the jar inside of my libs folder, and re synced the gradle. The gradle  has the dependency line to compile at the *.jar 's inside of the libs folder.

Comment: please post your build.gradle file